# How to select specific value on join condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains the details of a game, this table is called `match`, each match can have n goals, these goals are stored inside the table `goal`.

Suppose I have the following situation on `match`:

```
id = 2564824
home_team_half_time_score = 2
home_team_score = 4
away_team_half_time_score = 0
away_team_score = 0
```

so this record means that the `match` is ended 4 - 0 for the home team, what I want to know is: how can I get only the `goals` scored in the first time? in this case there are 2 goals scored in the first time, and have this id:

```
id    | match_id | result | minute 
16092   2564824    1 - 0     15
16093   2564824    2 - 0     43
16094   2564824    3 - 0     63
16095   2564824    4 - 0     78
```

I just need to get the `minute` field of each goal, how can I setup the query?

**SCHEMA**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `swp`.`match` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `round_id` INT NULL,
  `datetime` DATETIME NULL,
  `status` INT NULL,
  `gameweek` INT NULL,
  `home_team_id` INT NULL,
  `home_team_half_time_score` INT NULL,
  `home_team_score` INT NULL,
  `home_extra_time` INT NULL,
  `home_penalties` INT NULL,
  `away_team_id` INT NULL,
  `away_team_half_time_score` INT NULL,
  `away_team_score` INT NULL,
  `away_extra_time` INT NULL,
  `away_penalties` INT NULL,
  `venue_id` INT NULL,
  `venue_attendance` INT NULL,
  `aggregate_match_id` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `home_team_id_idx` (`home_team_id` ASC),
  INDEX `away_team_id_idx` (`away_team_id` ASC),
  INDEX `venue_id_idx` (`venue_id` ASC),
  INDEX `match_status_id_idx` (`status` ASC),
  INDEX `FK_competition_rounds_match_round_id_idx` (`round_id` ASC),
  INDEX `FK_match_match_aggregate_match_id_idx` (`aggregate_match_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_team_match_home_team_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`home_team_id`)
    REFERENCES `swp`.`team` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_team_match_away_team_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`away_team_id`)
    REFERENCES `swp`.`team` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_venue_match_venue_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`venue_id`)
    REFERENCES `swp`.`venue` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_match_status_match_status_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`status`)
    REFERENCES `swp`.`match_status` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_competition_rounds_match_round_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`round_id`)
    REFERENCES `swp`.`competition_rounds` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_match_match_aggregate_match_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`aggregate_match_id`)
    REFERENCES `swp`.`match` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
Thanks for any help.

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `swp`.`goal` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `team_id` INT NOT NULL COMMENT 'Team that has scored.',
  `player_marker_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `player_assist_id` INT NULL,
  `match_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `minute` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `result` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `type` INT NOT NULL COMMENT 'All the status that a goal can assume.',
  INDEX `player_marker_id_idx` (`player_marker_id` ASC),
  INDEX `player_assist_id_idx` (`player_assist_id` ASC),
  INDEX `match_id_idx` (`match_id` ASC),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `FK_goal_type_goal_goal_type_id_idx` (`type` ASC),
  INDEX `FK_team_goal_team_id_idx` (`team_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_player_goal_player_marker_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`player_marker_id`)
    REFERENCES `swp`.`player` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_player_goal_player_assist_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`player_assist_id`)
    REFERENCES `swp`.`player` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_match_goal_match_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`match_id`)
    REFERENCES `swp`.`match` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_goal_type_goal_goal_type_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`type`)
    REFERENCES `swp`.`goal_type` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_team_goal_team_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`team_id`)
    REFERENCES `swp`.`team` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**UPDATE**

actual query:

```
$query = "SELECT m.*,
  t.name AS team_name,
  t.id AS team_id,
  l.position AS team_rank,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN g.type = 5 THEN 1 END) AS failed_to_score,
  FROM `match` m
  LEFT JOIN goal g ON m.id = g.match_id
  LEFT JOIN team t ON t.id = :team_id
  LEFT JOIN league_ranking l ON l.team_id = :team_id AND l.round_id = :round_id
  WHERE m.round_id = :round_id
  AND m.status = 5 ";
```

Comment: show also the records for the second half

Comment: Are you wanting to show the goals scored in the first half or are you wanting to show the minutes of each goal in the first half or both?

Comment: It would be helpful if we could see the table schemas for match and goal.

Comment: What exactly does your input data look like and what do you want the result to be? For future reference, you'll get better answers (and less downvotes) if you follow this guideline: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @Analyst123456789 I just need the minute of half goal, I added also the schema of both table

Comment: @popop There must be something I'm missing. How does the first table even come in to play? You have a table with the goals scored in each minute and you just want to restrict to those which occurred before 45. Is the complexity accounting for stoppage time?.

Comment: @Error_2646 each `match` is part of a `round` a `round`is where each team play a `match`, each `round` is part of a competition. These details are useless in this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT minute, result FROM goal WHERE (CAST(minute AS UNSIGNED)<=45 OR minute like '45%') AND match_id='2564824'
```

if this is your starting point:

```
id    | match_id | result | minute 
16092   2564824    1 - 0     15
16093   2564824    2 - 0     43
16094   2564824    3 - 0     63
16095   2564824    4 - 0     78
```

If this is indeed your expected results then you have to show the input data to get this result

**UNTESTED**

```
SELECT m.*,
  t.name AS team_name,
  t.id AS team_id,
  l.position AS team_rank,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN g.type = 5 THEN 1 END) AS failed_to_score,
  g.minute
  FROM `match` m
  LEFT JOIN goal g ON m.id = g.match_id
  LEFT JOIN team t ON t.id = :team_id
  LEFT JOIN league_ranking l ON l.team_id = :team_id AND l.round_id = :round_id
  WHERE m.round_id = :round_id
  AND m.status = 5 "
  AND (CAST(minute AS UNSIGNED)<=45 OR minute like '45%');
```

This integrated query will stop the analysis of each match to the first half. I'd keep the two queries as separate

Comment: the column contains a varchar, infact some goal are scored with an extra time like 45 + 3' so I canno use your solution, +1 anyway

Comment: see my edit. This way you will get also those results that you say are like 45+something

Comment: is possible to add your query to mine instead of executing two requests? Check my update please

Comment: yes you can. it's trivial to add it. You can do it in seconds

Comment: could you please show me how? I'm not an sql expert yet

Comment: heh thanks, but for some cases like this I still have a bit of difficulty